# Bivariate distribution of the discrete type question

Tags: probability, statistics, bivariate-distributions

A homework questions asks:

> John has two quarters and two dimes. He tosses these four coins 3 times. Let U be the number of heads of quarters, and V be the number of heads of dimes.
>   Denote X = U + V and Y = |U − V |. Find P(X = 3, Y = 1).

The given answer is: .25

I'm not sure how to get there. I figured if X = U + V, and we want X = 3, then the possible pairings are: (0,3) (1,2) (2,1) (3,0)

If Y = |U-V| and we want Y = 1, then the possible pairings are:
(0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,4) (4,5) (5,6) (6,5) (5,4) (4,3) (3,2) (2,1) (1,0)

But after getting all the pairings I'm blanking on how to get the probability. I feel like it's probably really simple too, but I just can't seem to remember how to get to the final answer.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 ways for X=3 and Y=1, namely (1,2) and (2,1).  Each of these has 2 ways of happening (2 heads for quarters and either head for dimes and vice versa).  There are$2^4=16$ possible outcomes all together.  Probability therefore is 1/4.

Tossing 3 times doesn't effect probability.  If X and Y are the sum for all 3 sets of tosses, then it is a different question.

Comment: So wait, does that mean the 3 times literally means nothing? Like it's just asking the probability for any one round of flipping all 4 coins?

Comment: Your the one that stated the problem.  That's what it sounds like to me.